# TransitionStylePartialCurl Not working with ios 4.3

Tags: objective-c, uiviewanimation, uimodaltransitionstyle

UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl is not working with ios 4.3, but when i have exactly the same code,it works with ios5.

```
ViewController *infoView = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

[infoView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[infoView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:infoView.view animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I dont get that,is this a bug with ios 4.3 for transition,
does any one have a work around?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl):

> This transition style is supported only if the parent view controller is presenting a full-screen view and you use the UIModalPresentationFullScreen modal presentation style. Attempting to use a different form factor for the parent view or a different presentation style triggers an exception.

You are using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` instead of `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` and thus **it is not supported.**

Comment: i also used UIModalPresentationFullScreen instead but is gives same result for ios 4.3

Comment: so is the parent view full screen?

Comment: btw.. unless you are doing other animations you shouldn't have to do `[UIView commitAnimations];` after you present the modal view... the modal presentation will animate itself

Comment: parent view is not full screen (with tab bar controller) but it is presenting a full screen view controller, as per apple docs

Comment: Like I said in the other comment: are you doing some other animations at the same time? (You have `[UIView commitAnimations];` in there). If you are not doing other animations, what happens if you remove it? Also, what happens if you let the tab bar controller (or root view controller) present the modal view? Does that work?

Comment: No,no other animations are running. i needed to present a another view controller from the present view controller just as modal view on the top through page curl, but why does same code works with ios5